# cant change colour of <a> link

Tags: css

trying to set the colour of my links to a certain colour and remove the outline, but it doesnt work. I have this set as my style for the links:

```
    <style>
        a:link, a:visited, a:active, a:hover {
            text-decoration:none
            font-size:35
            color:#FFFFFF
        }
    </style>
```

Here is the line for links I am trying to change:

`<a href="/index.html">HOME</a> <a href="page2.html">PAGE2</a>`

I have tried cleaning the browser cache, holding CTRL when refreshing, and it just doesn't work. It flashes white for a split second but turns back to the ugly underlined purple.

Comment: Typo: You forgot the semi-colons after each property: value pair in the CSS. (Also the units for the font size).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing semicolons after each line and a unit after 35.